# Double quotes are deleted from string passed as argument to sh in Jenkinsfile

Tags: string, bash, jenkins, escaping, jenkins-pipeline

Specifying

```
sh "bash -c \"echo Hello world\""
```

in a declarative pipeline in a `Jenkinsfile` results in

```
bash -c echo Hello world
```

being executed. I'd expect the escaping of the double quotes in the string to be resolved to double quotes like so

```
bash -c "echo Hello world"
```

Now, the quotes are simply deleted which is very unexpected if not buggy. I'd like to understand what's happening and eventually suggest and improvement to the Jenkins devs.

This might be another case of [Jenkinsfile idiosynchrasies with escaping and quotes](https://gist.github.com/Faheetah/e11bd0315c34ed32e681616e41279ef4), however I don't seem to find the matching one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to play with the single quote:

```
sh "bash -c 'echo Hello world'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is

```
sh """bash -c "echo Hello world" """
```

This allows you to keep the double quotes for the cases you need interpolation inside your command.